# Django: 'current_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: python, django, portability

I have a small Django project I received from a friend. The code works perfectly on his system. However, on my system I get the following error message when running the server:

> **TemplateSyntaxError at /**
>
> 'current_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library current_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.current_tags

The problem is with a line in an html file:

```
{% load current_tags %}
```

This exact same code works on his system with no errors. What could that be?

Comment: In the interest of saving others the 20 minutes I spent rooting through these questions: if you've just created your custom tags file (this is your first custom tag in a given app), you'll need to restart the Django development server so that it can pick up the new file. This error is displayed when that is your only problem too.

Comment: @chucksmash Thank you Jesus.

Comment: remember to restart the dev-server

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. (Most likely) You haven't installed one of the dependencies of your tag library. Check the imports inside the `current_tags.py` module.
2. Make sure the application that includes the tag library is registered in `settings.py` under `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. Make sure that you can successfully import the tag library.

   ```
   python manage.py shell
   >>> from app.templatetags import current_tags
   ```

   This boils down what the following link recommends, which is that the error itself tends to mislead you about where it's looking for a template from. It silently ignores errors on import, which means `current_tags.py` itself might have a syntax error or another reason why it raises ImportError.

If everything else fails, check this link:
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/dec/04/magic-tags/

Comment: If those don't work, check the **order of apps** in INSTALLED_APPS. If one of your apps uses a template tag from another app, that second app is by definition a dependency and must be listed before.

Comment: If still not working, remove your .pyc files and try again (that solved my problem once)

Comment: Similar to the comment above, I've tried numerous fixes and I didn't notice that other Django console instances were being used, which caused some libraries not to refresh! If you think everything's ok and just can't find the problem, close all running instances and try again.

Comment: Don't forget to turn it on and off again ;), meaning, don't forget to restart the server

Comment: Maybe this is silly advice but restart your runserver.  You get used to it reloading every time you change python code but the reload is either not triggered by adding a new template tag file or it does not register new template tag libraries.

Comment: stuck on #3 - can't even launch the shell - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ProjectName.templatetags.custom_tags'"

Answer (score 78):

I had this problem and fixed it by adding a blank `__init__.py` file in my appname/templatetags/ directory.

Comment: I had to restart dev server.

Answer (score 64):

Possibilities are many:

1. You haven't reset your **dev server**.
2. You have **dependency loop** in templatetag file.
3. You **misspelled** something (directory, folder, template name in 'load', etc.).
4. You forgot about adding the app to **INSTALLED_APPS**.

Answer (score 13):

**Restart the server** has solved the issue for me. They must have mentioned it in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error but for a different reason so I'll tell you (in case someone else comes the same problem).

I had everything right but I had my custom tag inside a folder named `template_tags` and after a long search I found out that it had to be `templatetags`, and now it works. So **check the folder name is exactly `templatetags`**.

Comment: Excellent answer. Django's error message is not obvious in this case.

Comment: I was about to add this answer, in case it wasnt here already. Exactly my problem :P

Answer (score 6):

suppose you have the following structure:

-- Application_Name

-------templatetags

--------------**init**.py

--------------templates_extras.py

-------**init**.py

-------settings.py

-- manage.py

You have to make sure of the following:

- your application itself inside which your "templatetags" is resident is actually installed in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py (e.g. "Application_Name")
- your tag module itself that exists inside "templatetags" is already installed in INSTALLED_APP in settings.py (e.g. "ApplicationName.templatetags.tempaltes_extras")
- keep sure you have "**init**.py" under templatetags directory
- you have to restart the server
- In some cases you have to remove all generated *.pyc if it did not work then retry again

Comment: your tag module itself that exists inside "templatetags" is already installed in INSTALLED_APP in settings.py (e.g. "ApplicationName.templatetags.templates_extras")
This was crucial! You would assume 'ApplicationName' would be enough in settings.py but that is not so. Thank you!

Comment: No module named 'ApplicationName.templatetags.templates_extras"

Answer (score 5):

"custom tags" is not a valid tag library error, more often is occurred because the custom tags are not loaded into the app.

place an empty **init**.py inside the same folder where your "custom template tag" is placed and run the below code on the terminal to load the custom template tags

```
touch __init__.py
```

Comment: Despite having the right directory structure, and having the __init__.py file already in there... I got this error until I ran this command.  Thank you!

Comment: I still get a ModuleNotFound error (when i try to restart the server)

Answer (score 5):

For others facing this . Suppose your App name is `MyApp` and your tag folder name is `templatetags` then in `settings.py` you should have :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'MyApp',
'MyApp.templatetags'
]
```

Both your django app and your tag folder which is under your app package are needed there.

```
-> MyApp
    ---> models.py
    ---> views.py
    ---> templatetags
      -----> __init__.py
      -----> app_filters.py
```

And in your template file :

```
{% load app_filters %}
```

Also `app_filters.py` be like :

```
# coding=utf-8
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='get_item')
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

check all above steps and you may find the issue.

Comment: I used to make the mistake to load the specific tag rather than the file containing the tag. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure your templatetags folder is initialized with python, if you are in doubt, just take bakup of all files,

Remove all files,
Inside templatetags folder create **init**.py file only,
then restart your server,

Now your folder is under Python, then do your stuff.

This works for me...

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was the mistake of putting quotes around the library name in `load` tag.

WRONG: `{% load 'library_name' %}`

CORRECT: `{% load library_name %}`

Refer to other answers too. I solved a couple of those problems too before landing here.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `load` statement is correct. It should be the name of the file, not the name of the app. For instance, if you have this app:

```
appname
├── __init__.py
├── templatetags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foobarfilename.py
```

Then you should put this in your template:

```
{% load foobarfilename %}
```

Of course, you should check the other answers too.

Answer (score 2):

After you have created the template tag and it should be within the 'templatetags' package within an app installed in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS, make sure you restart your dev-server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this useful: somehow I had named the directory `'templatetags '` instead of `'templatetags'`, that is -- with a space at the end. Took hours to finally realize.

Answer (score 0):

All of the advice listed here didn't help me. So in my specific case the problem was that the templatetag had to be loaded from a third-party app, and I manually copied source folder with that app into `src` folder in my virtualenv. Then I ran `python setup.py install` inside that folder. After that django could not load this module.

Then I removed the source and installed folder of this app and installed it using `pip install -r requirements.txt` after adding a relevant line into `requirements.txt` file. It was downloaded into the `src` folder, installed and everything began working properly. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case
I have created library instance using **tag** variable instead of **register** variable

```
tag = template.Library()
```

But it should be

```
register = template.Library()
```

> To be a valid tag library, the module must contain a module-level
>   variable named register that is a template.Library instance, in which
>   all the tags and filters are registered

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was,
I was using `{% load filter_method_name %}`

I had to change to `{% filename %}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was - I am using

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template-to-use.html')
```

I forgot to create that template and right away it started working. I know above answers are more related to most of the issues - but hope maybe someone find it useful. It should have gotten to me:

```
Template does not exist
```

but it did not and this worked.