# Is there a way to access custom template tags and filters in all apps of a Django project?

Tags: django, templatetags

I have a dynamic html element that will appear on many pages in multiple apps. I'd like to resuse my custom templatetag / filter / inclusion tag code, say by putting it all in one app called utils. But when I try to load one such tag I am continually told that **'xyz' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:**...

Please help!

Comment: That should work I would think. One consideration noted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493776/django-current-tags-is-not-a-valid-tag-library) is that the app containing the template tag must be loaded before the apps using it (ie. settings.py INSTALLED_APPS). If your template tag was working before moving it to another app then the issue is likely just something with how you are loading it in now.

Comment: @fredriksapps The template engine is initialized way before the first template is rendered. I'd be really surprised if the order of `INSTALLED_APPS` mattered in any way in this case.

Comment: @r_zelazny are you loading the template tag library in the template where you are trying to use it? If so can you show me this? [Django Custom Template Tags Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/)