# Django Custom Tag - Tag Not Registered

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've referred extensively to some of the great answers at [Django: 'current_tags' is not a valid tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493776/django-current-tags-is-not-a-valid-tag-library/21588088#21588088) , but can't solve the problem with any permutation of the suggested solutions.

Here's the vanilla structure in my project folder:

```
templatetags
-> __init__.py
-> custom_tags.py
```

I have the line `{% load custom_tags %}` in my html file, which extends base.html.

In settings.py, "project_name" is included in INSTALLED_APPS. Like mif suggests, I try `python manage.py shell`. Without altering settings, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'custom_tags'`.

If I add the entry `project_name.templatetags.custom_tags` to INSTALLED_APPS, then my aforementioned attempt to launch the shell fails with two exceptions: `AttributeError: module 'demos.templatetags' has no attribute 'custom_tags'`, and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demos.templatetags.custom_tags'`.

custom_tags.py is quite simple:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def str_concat(a):
    return str(a) + " eyy"                                                      
#register.filter('str_concat', str_concat)
```

I've run the file (with `python custom_tags.py`) with that last line commented and uncommented. I've also `touch` 'd both custom_tags and **init**. I've also relaunched the dev server numerous times (via ctl+c and `python manage.py runserver`). Also, I've confirmed that the two imports in custom_tags work fine and are successfully installed in the venv.

Comment: You shouldn't add the project folder to installed_apps. Create a new app (with `manage.py startapp`), add it to installed_apps, and put the template tags in there.

Comment: thank you, that was the key! surprised none of the other answers made this explicit. if you want to post a brief answer, i will accept it